# What is the maximum level skills can reach? Some skill levels appear to cross 100

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

What is the max level skills you can reach in skyrim?

Answer (score 2):

Some items raise your skill level (e.g. Necklace of the Major Squire raises Light Armor 17 points). Without equipment or potion modifiers, the maximum level is 100.

Answer (score 2):

Skill levels in Skyrim are your Base Skill (15-100) plus any Fortify Potions and Enchantments.

- Most fortify skill enchantments may be applied to 4 equipment slots.
- If you rely solely on drops, the maximum fortify skill enchantment will be +25.  Skilled Enchanters can do significantly better.
- If you rely solely on drops, the maximum fortify skill potion will be +25.  Again, Skilled Alchemists can do significantly better.

As such, with some exceptions, a character who does no enchanting or alchemy can expect to be able to boost those skills that are fortified in this manner to about **225**.  Alchemist/Enchanters can do even better.

---

For completeness' sake, there are a few *flavors* of Fortify (Skill) effects in Skyrim.

- Some, as discussed above, add to the character's numeric skill value.
- Others, instead add a percentage to the the effect of your actions, specifically attack damage or armor value.
- Fortify Enchantments for Spell Schools will generally reduce casting costs.
- Fortify Potions for some spell schools will boost spell duration instead of effect.